# For what value $k$ is $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2} & x \neq 2 \\ k & x = 2 \end{cases}$ continuous at $x=2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

For what value $k$ is the following function continuous at $x=2$?
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2} & x \neq 2 \\
k & x = 2
\end{cases}$$

---

All those square roots are weighing me down!  And $k$?  My mind's not where it's supposed to be today.  Thanks in advance for posting a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must have $f(2) = \lim_{x \to 2}(\frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2})$ for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x=2$. Since plugging in $2$ gives us $\frac{0}{0}$, we can use L'hopital's Rule and differentiate the top and bottom:

$$\lim_{x \to 2}(\frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2})=\lim_{x \to 2}(\frac{2\frac{1}{2}(2x+5)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{2}(x+7)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{1})$$

$$\lim_{x \to 2}(\frac{2\frac{1}{2}(2x+5)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{2}(x+7)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{1})=\frac{1}{6}$$

So we see that we need $f(2)=\frac{1}{6}$, so $f(2) = k = \frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x+5}-\sqrt{x+7}}{x-2}=\frac1{\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt{x+7}}\xrightarrow[x\to2]{} ...$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac { \sqrt { 2x+5 } -\sqrt { x+7 }  }{ x-2 } =\frac { \left( \sqrt { 2x+5 } -\sqrt { x+7 }  \right) \left( \sqrt { 2x+5 } +\sqrt { x+7 }  \right)  }{ \left( x-2 \right) \left( \sqrt { 2x+5 } +\sqrt { x+7 }  \right)  } =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2x+5 } +\sqrt { x+7 }  } $$